# how to find all global variables at runtime?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I've a very large C program consisting of hundred of files; I want to
know what are all
the global variables defined in the program. how do i do this.

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to know this at runtime, how are they supposed to change?

Comment: I want to snapshot/store it in a file.

Comment: Can you use a debugger?

Comment: Are you talking about the variable names and types (known at compile-time) or their content/value (known at runtime)?

Comment: @Nabla: yes, i want this things.

Comment: @PhillipKinkade: yes ,i can use.

Comment: My question was not a yes/no question. Which of the two things do you want?

Comment: @PhillipKinkade: I want variable name and its memory address.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial may be useful, make appropriate changes as per your needs.[Clang Tutorial](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html)

You can also check the symbol table  `objdump -x file.o` which contains the list of variable's.

Comment: try objdump -t  file.o it gives out only symbol table. Also give a look into "nm".

Comment: I got symbol table. It contains many things so how i can extract global variable only.